# how to search a string in pdf content (C#)?

Tags: c#, file, pdf, full-text-search

I have two emergency questions  !
1- how to search a string in pdf file (in c#) ?
2- how to insert custom user control (C# controls) to pdf file ?

Comment: to give you a quick answer 1 is possible, 2 is not (a usercontrol with logic anyway)

Answer (score 3):

Stack overflow already has an answer to your first question. Have a look at this : [How to programatically search a PDF document in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567951/how-to-programatically-search-a-pdf-document-in-c)

EDIT - and perhaps this : http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/5046-Search-String-PDF-File.aspx