# Count number of minus signs in a PDF document using C#

Tags: c#, pdf

I am trying to count the number of minus signs in a PDF document.

I have tried opening the document using a binary editor and see that the characters cannot be identified directly.

Anyone know how to do this? Preferably using C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work for [Atalasoft](http://www.atalasoft.com) on PDF technologies.  You can use our PdfTextDocument class to do that pretty easily:

```
int minusCount = 0;
using (PdfTextDocument doc = new PdfTextDocument(pdfStream)) {
    using (PdfTextReader reader = doc.GetPdfTextReader()) {
        int c = 0;
        while ((c = reader.Read()) >= 0) { // return < 0 at end
           if ((char)c == '-') minusCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with [ITextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/), it helps you to decode a pdf and extract the text in it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a library, [like this one for example](http://www.itextpdf.com/), to convert the pdf doc into something that you can actually parse as text. See [this forum post and answer](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/27) for that library for some quick answers.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this question [How to programatically search a PDF document in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567951/how-to-programatically-search-a-pdf-document-in-c)