# Parsing pdf files

Tags: c#, parsing, pdf, pdf-scraping

I have a requirement to split a large pdf document into smaller files based on the content of the file. We use BCL easyPDF to manipulate pdf files. easyPDF can split pdf documents based on a page number, but it cannot split the document based on the file content. Also it does not have a search function (as far as I can tell, if I am wrong please someone let me know.) to determine the location of the content.

Now can someone tell me how I can find the location of text in a pdf file using .net?

Thanks

Comment: yes but it should/is a community where we can help people who may be still learning the ins and outs of a language or protocol.  We can try to point them in the right direction.

Comment: Isn't PDF a sort of binary file? You cannot just parse it as text. A library is required

Comment: I start out my year with my usual complaint. Why is this off topic ( I know the rules say it is) but its very useful, many of the preserved, 'best' questions (which you cannot find now I see) are of this nature. They represent the accumulated advice (aka wisdom) of many experienced devs

Answer (score 3):

You might try [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) for your task.

The library can [extract text from PDFs (with or without formatting)](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/pdf-text/extract).

Or you could just retrieve a collection of [words with their bounding rectangles from PDFs](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Text/ExtractTextByWords). This should help you to find location of the text in a file.

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.

Comment: NOTE: As Bobrovsky mentions, this is a commercial product. Its price is non-trivial (though appropriate for what it does).

Answer (score 2):

You need a PDF library in .NET such as iText.Net.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this question.  there are links to some libraries that may satisfy your requirements

[How to programatically search a PDF document in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567951/how-to-programatically-search-a-pdf-document-in-c-sharp)