# What's the quickest way to search a network location?

Tags: c#, search

I have a network directory with thousands of files in several different subdirectories.  I've been using Windows Explorer search to find files but it takes too long when I need to perform several consecutive searches.  I'm interested in creating a C# form that will make this easier to do.  Note that this file structure does not change often (if ever) so setting up some DB to hold file names / locations wouldn't be a bad thing, so long as I don't have to enter them manually.

Bonus question: the majority of the documents are PDFs... how can I have my search include text in the file itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want to search for files, the DB you will need can be just a big array / list / [hashtable](http://www.dotnetperls.com/hashtable) which are all available in C#. (Hashtable would be pretty good for what you want which is quick lookup, if you use the filename as the index).

To Insert all the files of a folder and all subfolders recursively into your DB you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929276/how-to-recursively-list-all-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c).

And finally if you want to search inside the pdf you will probably need to do some work with indexing to make it fast. [Here is how to read .pdf in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567951/how-to-programatically-search-a-pdf-document-in-c-sharp)